# Sumar los valores de la ultima fecha registrada en un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buen día, estoy intentado obtener la sumatoria de los valores de los registros con la ultima fecha.
Tengo un DF parecido al siguiente

```
import pandas as pd 

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Trimestre':['1t 2020','2t 2020','3t 2020','4t 2020','1t 2021','2t 2021','3t 2021','4t 2021','4t 2021','4t 2021'],
                    'Cantidad':[250,400,300,100,500,200,450,100,300,400],
                    'Ciudad':['México','USD','China','Brasil','México','USD','China','Brasil','Japon','España']})
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a obtener la sumatoria del ultimo trimestre? En este caso sería el 4t 2021, no importa que la cantidad de distintos países se junte, justo estoy buscando eso

¿Habrá manera de que python detecte automáticamente el ultimo trimestre y de ahí hacer la sumatoria ? Para no cambiar la variable cada vez que se agrega un trimestre nuevo

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu columna `Trimestre` fuera un tipo de dato DateTime, una forma muy simple de detectar el ultima seria obteniendo el máximo de la columna. En tu caso es solo una columna de tipo `str` y el máximo es siguiendo orden lexicográfico:

```
>>> '4t 2020' < '1t 2021'
False
```

aun así podrías aplicar la misma lógica con algunos matices:

```
max_t = max(DF1["Trimestre"], key=lambda x: f"{x[-4:]}{x[0]}")
```

En este caso se usa el builtin `max` en vez de `pandas.Series.max` porque admite el argumento `key`. Lo que hacemos con el es generar una nueva cadena con el año seguido del trimestre, esta cadena sera la que se usa para ordenar.

La ventaja es que es muy simple y no tenemos que hacer conversiones a `int`, `DateTime`, etc. Pero:

- Se sigue usando orden lexicográfico, pero no tendrás problemas mientras tu año este entre 1000 y 9999.
- Todas las cadenas de tu columna deben tener exactamente el formato "nt yyyy".

Puedes modificar la función clave para que realice un parseo mas robusto de la cadena para evitar errores en caso de encontrar cadenas que no sigan el formato anterior exactamente. Igualmente se puede evitar los problemas derivados del orden lexicográfico retornando enteros, por ejemplo una tupla de la forma `(año: int, trimestre: int)`.

Tras ello puedes usar indexado boolean, query o lo que quieras para hacer la suma:

```
sumatoria = DF1.loc[DF1['Trimestre'] == max_t, 'Cantidad'].sum()
```

Si vas a operar mucho con estos datos quizás te convendría usar un tipo de dato mas afable que `str` para representar el trimestre y que permita comparar, agrupar y ordenar de forma correcta por defecto, incluida la posibilidad de crear tu propia clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias en verdad 
Me sirvió perfectamente y en la manera en que lo explicaste igual lo entendí super bien 
Muchas gracias